# Max count by customer and category

Tags: sql, count, max

I have transactional data that looks like this

```
Account  ProductCategory  
   1           a
   1           a
   1           b
   2           c
   2           d
   2           d
```

I need to find the ProductCategory that appears most per customer. Results:

```
Account  ProductCategory
   1           a
   2           d
```

My result was a long with many nested subqueries. Any good ideas?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI-standard window functions, particularly `row_number()`.  You can use this with aggregation to get what you want:

```
select Account, ProductCategory
from (select Account, ProductCategory, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by Account order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by Account, ProductCategory
     ) apc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using analytic SQL , or just using count over group. The syntax depends on the RDBMS, as asked by Michael .

you can try following SQL :

```
select * from
(select account, ProductCategory, ct , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by account, ProductCategory  ORDER BY ct DESC ) As myRank
from  (select account, ProductCategory, count(0) as ct
       from <table>
       group by account, ProductCategory  ) t ) t2
where t2.myRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT [Account], ProductCategory, COUNT([ProductCategory]) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductCategory) AS [Count]
           FROM tbl_all)
SELECT A.Account, ProductCategory
FROM A INNER JOIN (SELECT Account, MAX([Count]) AS Count FROM A GROUP BY A.Account) AS B ON A.Account=B.Account AND A.Count=B.Count
GROUP BY A.Account, ProductCategory
```